# Ubuntu caused my machine to boot to a blank screen!

Tags: boot, screen, 32-bit, windows-xp

Tested the most recent Ubuntu 32bit on my old Windows xp desktop from the DVD I burned. Everything ran smoothly, so I rebooted. My aim was to extract the last handful of files off the drive before doing a full install. Only thing is, it doesn't boot into either xp or Ubuntu now. It powers on to a blank screen. I tried hitting f8 at boot but the only thing I've had so far is a blank screen with a cursor. I'm out of ideas! Anyone ever come across this before?

*There are no actions I can perform from this screen. The Ubuntu DVD doesn't boot either.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

FIXED: *XP seems to have been damaged when I ran Ubuntu off the DVD somehow. Not sure how since all I did was check to see if it ran. Managed to get into bios after a ton of restarts and prevent it from attempting to boot off the hard drive. Go me!*